# excel background save via vba

Tags: vba, excel

The `Workbook.Save` line in my macro is holding everything up, and while it's important that there's a save step at the end of the macro, I don't mind if it just starts saving and then hands control back to the user.

Is there such a thing as `Workbook.Save BackGround` or `Workbook.Save vbModeLess`?

Comment: While the application is *saving* the workbook -- even when done manually from Ctrl+S or the ribbon/menu, etc. the user does **not** "have control" of the workbook. The application becomes *necessarily* un-interactive during the save procedure.  What functionality are you trying to give the user *while* the file is being saved?

Comment: I'd ideally like them to be able to do anything they like. The file's quite big, and the saves can take upwards of 45 seconds.

Comment: you can interject a pause so the macro doesnt run off

Comment: When the user manually saves the file, they absolutely **cannot do anything they like**. In fact, they can do **nothing at all** except wait for the save to finish. The same occurs when you invoke the `.Save` method of the workbook object, or the `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FileSave"`, etc. Do you understand why this is necessary?  What exactly is being "held up" by the save in your macro, which would not normally be "held up" by a user-invoked Save event?

Comment: You're correct that excel is also stopped by a manual save, but in the case of this macro it would be better if it weren't. If there's no additional options or alternative functions, then that's fine and just means the answer to my question is "no"

Comment: Why would it be better?  Your problem may be solved simply by informing the users that a `Save` is about to take place, and letting them know that this may take 45s+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there such a thing as `Workbook.Save BackGround` or `Workbook.Save vbModeLess`?

Definitively, no. The full list of methods available to the workbook object:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff847316(v=office.14).aspx

The `.Save` method does not have any optional arguments:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff197585(v=office.14).aspx

It seems you are perceiving a "problem" with your code which is not actually a problem, but normal and expected functionality, as I explained in the comments above:

- When a user manually saves the file, the application is not interactive. The user can't do anything except wait for the save to finish.
- The same occurs when you invoke the `.Save` method of the workbook object, or the `Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "FileSave"`, etc.

**This is necessary** because (obviously) changes made *while saving* would not be saved, but the workbook's `.Saved` property would display `True`.

This property is used in determining whether to show the "Close this workbook with unsaved changes?" dialog when the user closes the file.  If the property is `True`, then the user can close without any prompt.  But of course if you let them make changes this will inevitably lead to unwanted data loss as the user may then close the file with saved state `True` and unsaved changes to the workbook which have not been reflected in the `Saved` property.

(Note: there are probably more technical reasons, too, but this is just the common-sense explanation)

If the length of time it takes to save the file is burdensome, you have at least a few options I can think of, first you would want to consider *notifying* the user that the file is going to be saved and this may take upwards of 45 seconds.  This way, they do not think the program is unresponsive or otherwise hanging.  You can do this with a `MsgBox` or a `UserForm` pretty easily.

Alternatively, you could use either of the above methods to prompt the user, i.e., "Do you want to save the file?"

Etc.

Comment: If the user makes changes during a background save in other apps it updates the .Saved property. I've seen this happen in photoshop http://blogs.adobe.com/jkost/2012/04/background-save-and-auto-save-features-in-photoshop-cs6.html

Comment: well this isn't photoshop :)

Comment: Sorry, posted early. There's background saving in excel http://m.wikihow.com/Enable-AutoRecover-and-AutoSave-in-Microsoft-Office-2010

Comment: AutoSave/AutoRecover does not actually save the document except for the event of a crash.

Comment: Ok, cool. It's a shame, but hopefully a feature for the next version of Excel. Or one in 5 generations!

Comment: I would put my money on 5 generations, given how slow MS is to roll out some features :)

Answer (score 0):

When excel saves a file it created a temporary file with a name like `A82732KS.tmp` and the quickly delete the original file and rename the temp file (possibly in an atomic operation). To do this excel has to release control of the file to avoid a sharing violation so it necessarily disables any changes in memory in order to guarantee that was is written on file and what is loaded in memory is identical.